# Como fazer inserts na criação da tabela no SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Gostaria de saber como fazer INSERT manuais na classe DatabaseHelper que estende da SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String BANCO_DADOS = "Agenda";
private static int VERSAO = 1;


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, BANCO_DADOS, null, VERSAO);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE amigo (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                " nome TEXT, telefone TEXT, " +
                " email TEXT, categoria INTEGER);"
    );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

O que eu queria era fazer INSERTs dentro do método onCreate da classe DatabaseHelper assim como foi criado a tabela, mas não sei como fazer.

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em português. Procure fazer uma pergunta de cada vez. Fica melhor responder e para consultar mais tarde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer o INSERT da mesma forma que fez com o CREATE, passando o comando SQL na função execSQL.

Não é recomendado fazer consultas SQL direto da aplicação. O ideal é trabalhar com provedores de conteúdo (Content Providers) que atuam como uma camada de abstração entre o banco de dados e a aplicação, deixando a base mais isolada e mais fácil de implementar evoluções ou compartilhamento dos dados com outras aplicações.

Além disso, se você for utilizar listas (RecyclerView)  para apresentar os dados usando um Loader para fazer a gestão da mesma, o uso de Content Provider é imprescindível.

Mais detalhes aqui sobre Content Providers: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html?hl=pt-br

Comment: Obrigado por responder, entendi a parte do INSERT na função execSQL.
Mas e pra fazer consultas com INNER JOIN ou consultas que precisem de 2 ou mais parâmetros. Como faço?

Comment: Como disse antes, o ideal é sempre fazer acesso ao banco usando o Content Provider e o método dele para fazer query no banco é o "query()" que recebe uma única tabela como parâmetro.

Como você quer fazer um INNER JOIN entre 2 tabelas, prá não complicar muito, eu criaria uma VIEW no banco de dados fazendo o INNER JOIN necessário e depois passaria essa view no método query que citei acima. Tem outros métodos, mas acredito esse ser mais simples.